# Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 super key mapping into Android Studio keymap

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I am switching between OSx and Ubuntu Gnome (which is fantastic btw) and want to try and have the same shortcuts inside Android Studio. I am using a wired mac keyboard and `CMD` is default mapped to be the `Super` key, which is fine. However, I would like to map this inside of AS so I can use `Super` as part of key combos i.e. `SUPER+E`. It only seems to register `SUPER+SHIFT` and no other combo - is there something about ubuntu gnome that is blocking this or am I missing something obvious? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the gnome `Tweak` tool I can map right super only to expose the desktop which then allows me to use L-SUPER inside AS as part of a key combo :)

Comment: What's that tweak tool you are talking about?